# Compatibility of ROS-melodic with Gazebo 11

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

Hellow everyone,
I have recently downloaded gazebo 11 and ROS melodic but whenever I go to launch my robot application, I get the following error.

... logging to /home/home/.ros/log/77df126e-778d-11ea-87b5-363bebb00921/roslaunch-home-H110M-S2-4832.log

Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.

Press Ctrl-C to interrupt

Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Resource not found: simple_arm

ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros

ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/melodic/share

The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

I even tried

sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-gazebo-ros-control

but it didnt work.It says it depends on gazebo 9 but how can Imake it work for gazebo 11

Comment: How did you install Gazebo11? I build Gazebo11 and gazebo_ros_pkgs from source on Melodic and everything works fine.

Comment: You need the proper ROS packages for Gazebo 11, see my answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

In Melodic the default `gazebo-ros-control` is for Gazebo9. If you want to use Gazebo11 with Melodic you have to install the corresponding `gazebo11-ros-control` package like this:

```
$ sudo apt install ros-melodic-gazebo11-ros-control
```

Other relevant packages (if not installed automatically as dependencies)

- `ros-melodic-gazebo11-ros`
- `ros-melodic-gazebo11-msgs`
- `ros-melodic-gazebo11-plugins`
- `ros-melodic-gazebo11-ros-pkgs`
- `ros-melodic-gazebo11-dev`

Read more under `Gazebo 11.x series` series here http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros.

**Note!** Remember to remove `Gazebo9` first and also `ros-melodic-gazebo-ros-control`, else you may get an error from apt.

**Setup your computer to accept software from packages.osrfoundation.org**

Usually you only get the first release of Gazebo on the ROS distribution e.g. 9.0 or 11.0. If you want minor updates such as 11.3 as of writing, then add packages.osrfoundation.org to your package repo as per the guide here http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install

Usually you just have to do the following to get the newest Gazebo updates:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list'
$ wget https://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt update
```